# The browser overwrites the content of the message after receiving the response

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, dingo-api

I have a little problem with DingoAPI and Vue.js when I'm trying to get my error message from response. I think the browser is replacing my custom message by the default one. Here is my code:

PHP script

```
if($request->readerId){
      Return succes (this works properly)
else{
      return $this->response->error(
           'No reader',
           400 //(or diffrent code)
      );
}
```

Vue.js script

```
await axios.post(API_URL + 'card/', {
            some data
        }, {
            headers: {
                headers
            },
        }).then(({data}) => {
            context.commit(SET_RESPONSE, data);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
            throw error
        })
```

When I'm trying to look on my message in the network tab I can see (so DingoAPI did it correctly):

> {"message":"No reader","status_code":400}

But when I'm using `console.log(error.message)` or trying to show it on the page there is standard error message:

> Request failed with status code 400

Is there a way to set error message with DingoAPI and catch it in my .js script?
Maybe I need to write my own custom exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is access to the data of the response from your error variable.

```
console.log(error.response.data.message); // No reader
```

Otherwise you can log `error.response` to see the object:

```
console.log(error.response);
```

If you wonder why it's printing **Request failed with status code 400**:

> The problem is when the console.log tries to output the error, the string representation is printed, not the object structure, so you do not see the `.response` property.

Source: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960#issuecomment-309287911

Comment: That's it! I'm ashamed for me it was so simple